# Delete rows if 2 values exists in another data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I've got 2 data frames that contain the same columns.  One is called newGames, the other is called existingGames.  What I would like to do is check comapare the newGames game_pk and sv_id columns between the two data frames.  If the game_pk and sv_id exist in both table I would like to remove that row from the newGames data frame.

```
        N.game_pk   N.sv_id           E.game_pk   E.sv_id
 1      440697      123456_789012     NA          NA
 2      440698      123456_789012     440698      NA
 3      440699      123456_789012     440699      123456_789012
```

The e. stands for the existingGames data frame and N. stands for the newGames data frame.  What I would like to have in the end is a newGames data frame that shows all the columns where e.game_pk AND e.sv_id (WHOLE GAME) or e.sv_id (single pitch from game) do not exist in the existingGames data frame.  Sv_id is a time stamp so it is possible to have the same value for different game_pk's, so "combining" the fields makes the row unique.

this works for missing games (440697)

```
 newGames2 <- newGames[!(newGames$game_pk %in% existingGames$game_pk),]
```

but I tried

```
 newGames2 <- newGames[!(newGames$game_pk %in% existingGames$game_pk) | (!(newGames$game_pk %in% existingGames$game_pk) & !(newGames$sv_id %in% existingGames$sv_id)),]
```

and it just selects the full data frame instead of the single missing pitch.

Comment: You probably need to use `&` instead of `|`

Comment: Can you show sample of newGames and existingGames data frames? You should look at `anti_join` in the `dplyr` package.

Comment: @Gopala how can i do that?  FYI - The data frames have 76 columns.  Thanks!

Comment: @amatsuo_net  I left off part of the code, I've corrected it now.  Sorry!

Comment: You can select relevant columns and post the samples. Or, you can make up some data yourself and post that. Hard to provide working code without input data and expected output.

Comment: That's what the first chunk of code is.  See the n.game_pk and e.game_pk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how to do that with `anti_join` from `dplyr`:

```
new_game <- read.table(text="game_pk   sv_id
440697      123456_789012
440698      123456_789012
440699      123456_789012",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

existing_game <- read.table(text="game_pk   sv_id
NA          NA
440698      NA
440699      123456_789012",header=TRUE,stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

library(dplyr)
anti_join(new_game,existing_game)

  game_pk         sv_id
1  440698 123456_789012
2  440697 123456_789012
```

Comment: When I test it using your code it works and I see Joining, by = c("game_pk", "sv_id").  When I run it against the actual tables i get the same thing, Joining, by = c("game_pk", "sv_id"), but it returns all 3207 records instead of 1.  ExistingGames has 3206 records, newGames has 3207.  It should return the one missing pitch.  if sv_id exists for another game_pk, would that cause this problem?

Comment: Make sure columns for both tables are the same class and that there are no factors. `str(new_game)` and  `str(existing_game)` should be similar.

Comment: Additionally, although you are saying that it joins only on two columns, you also said that both data frames have 74 columns. Maybe you could try to specify which specific columns to join on like this here: `anti_join(new_game,existing_game, by = c("game_pk", "sv_id"))`

Comment: newGames2 <- anti_join(str(newGames), str(existingGames), by = c("game_pk", "sv_id")) returns an error Error in UseMethod("anti_join") : no applicable method for 'anti_join' applied to an object of class "NULL". savant2 <- anti_join(newGames, existingGames, by = c("game_pk", "sv_id")) returns all records like before.  I ran sapply(newGames, class and got   game_pk     sv_id 
"numeric"  "factor", sapply(existingGames, class) and got   game_pk     sv_id "integer"  "factor".  So the data doesn't match.  I should have tried this first.  Sorry!  Let me get them matching and try again.

Comment: No, don't include `str` in anti_join.